# Problems with Test::Class startup / setup inheritance

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing, inheritance

G'day,

I was using Test::Class perl module for some testing recently and ran into a strange problem. Basically, I have a base class inheriting from Test::Class

```
package Base::Class;
use base qw(Test::Class);

setup : Test(startup) {
    # Create a DB from scratch
}

teardown : Test(shutdown) {
    # DROP database 
}
```

And then I have a whole bunch of test classes inheriting this base class,

```
package Some::Class;
use base qw(Base::Class);

sub actually_relevant_tests { }
```

But when I run my test script:

```
use Some::Class;

Test::Class->runtests;
```

The DB is created and dropped TWICE? Once for the base class and once for the sub-class! How do you avoid this without the solution being an ugly hack?

Thanks.

Edit: The closest thing to elegance I have right now is -

```
use Test::Class;
my $object = Some::Class->new();
Test::Class->runtests($object);

package Some::Class;
use Base::Class;

sub actually_relevant_tests { }
```

But keeping question open for better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you eliminate a layer of the inheritance hierarchy? Why not delegate setup and teardown to helper functions?

```
package My::DB::Helpers;

sub setup_db {...}

sub teardown_db {...}
```

and then

```
package Some::Class;
use My::DB::Helpers;
use base 'Test::Class';

setup : Test(startup) {
    My::DB::Helpers::setup_db;
}

teardown : Test(shutdown) {
    My::DB::Helpers::teardown_db; 
}
```

Comment: Yup, could've done that if there were completely isolated from the class.. but they also set some class properties (should've mentioned that) and hence need to be properly inherited. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Gaurav hmm, not sure i can help you then, sorry. I haven't used Test::Class myself. If you do find the answer, post it here so we can learn from it! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your base class use:

```
sub SKIP_CLASS { shift eq __PACKAGE__ }
```

This ignores the `Base::Class` during runtests as an acutal `Test::Class` and accordingly startup/shutdown methods will only be called for `Some::Class`.